# Media query logical operator AND (max-width and max-height)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I'm using a vertical navbar on `@media (min-height: 490px)`; if height is smaller, it turns into a horizontal navbar.

It should collapse ONLY if `(max-width:300px) AND (max-height:490px)`. If `width < 300px` but `height > 490px`, it should not collapse.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 (Sass).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/A123_123A/j41bpu02/1/) with fake width and height, only to show what is wrong. It collapses every time `width < 300px`, even if `height is > 490px`;

Is it possible to accomplish what I need using only media queries? Or should I start trying it with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the style for your nav .collapse in the below media query. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j41bpu02/2/)

```
@media (min-height: 490px) {
#side-navbar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
   display: block!important;
}
.navbar-toggle {
   display: none !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just also added `display: none` to `.navbar-toggle` and it is works perfectly!